# How to sync a master database (MySQL) with multiple slaves using xml/json

Tags: mysql, json, xml, replication

Hi to everyone and thank you in advance,
I have to build a system to keep track of some records that will be updated weekly (at most), this system will be installed on at least 12 PC, many of which doesn't have internet connection, so I think the only option to feed the master server is exporting the data to a file (XML/JSON...) and importing it to the master...another requirement is that the master will have to generate another file to update the slave...the idea is to have all PCs synced as much as possible.
I already search using keywords like "techniques to sync databases using xml" but the best I found was an article that mentioned the need of a column to keep track which was updated last time...

Thank you all for your answers...I'll try to explain the idea I have so far...and the goals for the system...sorry for my bad English.

The system main use is to keep track and visualize the indicators like the number of births, percentage of poverty, etc. The system is part of the work between two NGOs and the government to help a district in Peru, being this district in a rural area where internet connection is only accessible in some points. The main requirements are:

- Keep track of the indicators with details like the value itself, the town it belongs, the date, etc.
- Visualize the data.
- Sync this data with a main server that will be the main resource for the planning and study, and sync back to the clients.
- Simple to install and operate because the users have little knowledge of computers or IT.

The idea I have so far is to build a system with PHP/MySQL/Apache that will be distributed using a portable webserver (uniserver zero XII) with the system preinstalled (included). The user will install a copy of it and register a new account in this client...account that will be used as a reference to differentiate the records once they are synced. Because some users wont have internet and the nature of the webserver (portable) I don´t think replication is an option as I thought in the beginning...so, my current idea of a solution is to export the data as XML or JSON...and import it in the main server, that also should export its data to update the client.

Hope I explain it correctly...please share with me your comments :)

Comment: Can you not just backup the master and restore to all the slaves, say once a week

Comment: Why with XML and JSON? Replication is already built into MySQL.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I forget to mention...the users are people with limited understanding of this matters so one the main requirements is that the system has to be as simple as possible.

Comment: @EJP, I know about replication but another of the requirements is that the system should work without internet connection because some of the slaves will be installed in PCs in rural areas where even mobile connection exists....I`ll edit my question to farther detail so maybe there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: did you try out replication. As mentioned in my answer and in the docs, replication works even when the servers are not always online.

Answer (score 3):

But why reinvent the wheel when the authors of mysql [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/5.1/en/replication.html) already solved this problem:

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master)
>   to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).
>   Replication is asynchronous - slaves need not be connected permanently
>   to receive updates from the master. This means that updates can occur
>   over long-distance connections and even **over temporary or intermittent
>   connections such as a dial-up service**. Depending on the configuration,
>   you can replicate all databases, selected databases, or even selected
>   tables within a database.

Emphasis mine.

You can shutdown your slave and when it starts up, it will replicate automatically get synced with the master.

Comment: Replication is the answer here. Rolling your own with XML or JSON is asking for a world of hurt.